# Помогите исправить ошибку "not a statement" и " ; expected"

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

```
 private void loadData() {
    ObservableList<User> data_table = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        data_table.add(new User(String.valueOf(i),
                 name: "name" + i, email: "email" + i, notes: "notes" + 1, new Button(text: "update")));
    }
```

Comment: В каком месте ошибка?

Comment: а что это у вс за синтаксис такой: new Button(text: "update")? я имею в виду двоеточие после text

Comment: @Эникейщик на 5 строке....

Comment: @Дмитрий ну это должна быть кнопка, чтобы отредактировать элементы в списке, поэтому и update....